# Select another row if a row is null

Tags: mysql

here i have two table. I want to know how to select another row if a row is null.
This is pages table

```
+----+-----------+
| id | page_type |
+----+-----------+
| 10 | product   |
| 12 | product   |
+----+-----------+
```

And this is content_descriptions table

```
+----+---------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
| id | page_id | language_code | title                                   |
+----+---------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  8 |      10 | id            | Cras dictum, tortor et faucibus feugiat |
| 11 |      10 | en            | Cras dictum, tortor et faucibus feugiat |
| 13 |      12 | md            | Nam pretium nunc massa, nec viverra     |
+----+---------+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Here i want to select from pages related to content_descriptions table where language_code is 'en'. But if different page_id does not have 'en' language_code, that page_id must be selected although the language_code is different.
I want to get result like this. But i can't.

```
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------+---------------+
| id | page_type | title                                   | language_code |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------+---------------+
| 10 | product   | Cras dictum, tortor et faucibus feugiat | en            |
| 12 | product   | Nam pretium nunc massa, nec viverra     | md            |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query produces the desired result:

```
SELECT p.*, 
  IF(cd_en.language_code IS NOT NULL, cd_en.title, cd.title) AS title,
  IF(cd_en.language_code IS NOT NULL, cd_en.language_code, cd.language_code) AS language_code
FROM pages AS p
  LEFT JOIN content_descriptions AS cd_en 
    ON (cd_en.page_id = p.id AND cd_en.language_code = 'en')
  LEFT JOIN content_descriptions AS cd
    ON (cd.page_id = p.id)
GROUP BY p.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86ade/1)

### What does it do?

- `SELECT`

  - `IF(cd_en.language_code IS NOT NULL, cd_en.title, cd.title) AS title` checks if a english title exists and use that if it does, otherwise use a different title from a random language (you didn't specify behavior in this case).
  - Same happens for `language_code`
- `FROM`

  - `LEFT JOIN content_descriptions AS cd_en ON (cd_en.page_id = p.id AND cd_en.language_code = 'en')` first joins the english version of the content to the pages
  - `LEFT JOIN content_descriptions AS cd ON (cd.page_id = p.id)` joins all languages for the fallback
- `GROUP BY` makes sure each page is only returned once

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for explained it completely. You has been helped my day.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select a.id, a.page_type,
   if(b.language_code='en',b.title,b.title) as title from pages a, 
   content_descriptions b where a.id=b.page_id
```

This might do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
p.id,p.page_type,cd.title,case when cd.language_code != 'en' then cd.language_code end 
from pages p
inner join content_descriptions cd on p.id = cd.page_id
where cd.language_code = 'en'
```

cant remember right now you may need: `group by p.id` at the end